# Open Graph actions object: renewing the access token

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, facebook, sdk

I have created a group of open graph "read" objects that I am looking to place on a site below featured articles.  Unfortunately the access tokens for these objects expire after about two hours.  This led me to the Facebook C# SDK, where I have had poor luck renewing these tokens… Has anyone come across a good starting example on how to renew the open graph objects?  Anyone?

Comment: You don’t want to _„renew Open Graph objects”_, you want to get a fresh user access token. And how that’s done is described well enough in the docs.

Comment: Is the access token for the articles the same as the user access token?  I have the users logging in via the C#SDK from which I get the user access token. However when I add an article buttons to a  page they come back as expired.